# HTTP POST request in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am creating a POST quest in Angular and have the following setup in the code

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
};
```

The below send 'Credentials' which is the following format

```
class Login
    {
        public username: string="";
        public Password: string="";
        public grant_type: string="";
    }
```

credentials is of type Login
and the call is

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl ,JSON.stringify(Credentials),httpOptions);
```

This seems to send the POST with nothing in it.

if I send using the following

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl ,JSON.stringify(Credentials));
```

it send the information but the Content-Type is being sent as 'text/plain' and therefore im getting a 415 error.

How can I correctly send this request.
I have checked the API is correct by using postman.

thanks

Alpesh

Comment: The `body` parameter should not be serialized with `JSON.stringify`. It will be done by the Angular `HttpClient`. However the `post` method is generic, so using `http.post<Credentials>()` would be the best.

Comment: I changed the post so it reads `return this.http.post<Login>(this.baseUrl,Credentials);` but this sends a blank body

Comment: can you add the code where you set the values for Credentials. are you initializing it with any values? or are you just sending empty strings

Comment: I have a form that asks for the user name and password. onSubmit, it calls a function that populates credentials `let credentials = this.formData
    console.log('onSubmit - ',credentials);`. in the console, it shows the correct information

Answer (score 1):

You calling JSON.stringify() on class, not on object.
Also, HttpClient internally serializes value that you pass in JSON, so most times you don't need to use it.

Try

```
const credentials: Credentials = {
  username: '',
  Password: '',
  grant_type: ''
};
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, credentials, httpOptions);
```

Comment: Sorry, I pasted it wrong. I have changed my original code in this question. Login is the class, credentials is of type class